# Android support library 23.2 - tab styling not working completely as before

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-styles, android-tablayout, android-appcompat

Some style attributes are no longer applied to my tabs after updating to android support library 23.2. I have a tab view as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        style="@style/WowTabAppearance" />
```

And the accompaniying styles:

```
<style name="WowTabAppearance" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/wow_tabs_bg</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/WowTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/dark_primary_color</item>
</style>
<style name="WowTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray_4_medium_light</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

textAllCaps now doesn't work - tabs display in uppercase on 23.2. I've tried changing other two attributes, and textColor works, while textSize doesn't.

Is this a bug in 23.2 or has something changed? Where could I see a more detailed report of changes in 23.2?

Comment: did you test with an older version, for example 23.1.1?

Comment: Yes, that is how I observed the change in the first place. Did the update, and all of a sudden my tabs became uppercase. Switched it back to 23.1.1, tabs went back to being lowercase (as I set them)

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202117.